# hook filter after the_content on a specific page

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I've made a function to hook after the_content. This is only working on certain pages/posts. It's working on the default template but not on my custom one's.

```
function insertFootNote($content) {
   $content.= "<div>";
   $content.="additional content";
   $content.= "</div>";
   return $content;
}

add_filter ('the_content', 'insertCpontent');
```

In my custom page template I haven the following code

```
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'part', 'addressbook' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in the template('part-addressbook.php) I have the following.

```
 echo '<div class="category-description"><p>'.get_the_content().'</p></div>';
```

On this template part the hook is not working although i'm using the_content/get_the_content function

Why does the hook does not work in this case?

Comment: at least somebody understood the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[get_the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) do not apply the_content filter. You have to apply it after receiving contents like following

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

It is also detailed at the bottom of [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

Answer (score 0):

You are already `echo`ing the data. Just use `the_content()`:

```
echo '<div class="category-description"><p>',the_content(),'</p></div>';
```

Please note: those are ***commas*** not periods. `echo` will accept multiple parameters separated by commas and you will not see the odd results you get if you try to concatenate. The above is functionally the same as:

```
echo '<div class="category-description"><p>';
  the_content();
echo '</p></div>';
```